# Oracle : System privileges, create user and grant privilages

Tags: oracle

I have the following connection properties.

> Connection Name: MyConnection
>
> UserName       : Scott
>
> password       : password

Now I want to create a user using the above connection. The query I tried to execute was,

```
CREATE USER demo IDENTIFIED BY demo;
```

but I got the **error** stating that

```
"insufficient privileges".
An attempt was made to change the current username or password
       without the appropriate privilege.
```

May I know how to create the user.

Answer (score 0):

To create a new user, you should connect as a account with DBA privileges, or the **System** user if there isn't a named DBA user.